# How to enable multiple worker(locust) nodes to access data sequentially from a single data source

Tags: locust

We have a scenario where we would like to have different locust worker nodes acquire and process data from a single data source like a database without reusing the data across the nodes.

Have you come across a similar scenario ? Can you please please guide .

Our locust test is currently set-up on cloud platform.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what `locust-plugins` MongoReader does. It might not be perfectly applicable to your use case, but at the very lest it can serve as an inspiration.

Source here: https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins/blob/master/locust_plugins/mongoreader.py

Example of use here:
https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins/blob/master/examples/mongoreader_ex.py

Comment: Thank you @Cyberwiz , from my understanding of the above solution we are updating/marking the data picked by an user/worker to ensure it is not available to the next user/worker . Please let me know if otherwise.

Comment: In my scenario we don't have write access on the db , how can we we handle this scenario?

Comment: You might instead try sharding the data somehow (using modulo or hash to select a subset of the data for each worker) and just iterating over the subset using a cursor. But you are on your own.